# Create a docker image so it can be used as base image

Tags: docker, containers

This question is a little vague. Sorry I do not have more details. I did an exam a few days ago that involved containers. One question was about optimizing an existing docker file, creating the image and pushing it to docker hub. The docker file included EXPOSE, CMD, LABEL, FROM RUN, ADD instructions.

One of the characteristics of the image was that one should be able to use it as base/parent image for creating other images.

I can't believe this mention was added for no reason. Yet I am not able to understand why this characteristic had to be listed. Is there something specific that one needs to add in docker files for base images? Or are base images stored differently in the registry?

What makes a base docker image different than a normal runnable image?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special that you need to do for an image to be reusable. All images can be used in the `FROM` clause and thus used as base images. The OS needs to match the commands in the file, of course. Also images are made of layers and layers are usually reused between images.

If I would have to look hard for a reason why that was specified as a requirement, I would say that they wanted you to pay attention to:

- the size of the final image (make it as small as possible)
- documentation (make it easy for others to understand what your image already does)